# asp.net core httpget method can't deserialize enum array

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, deserialization

asp.net core 2.2  httpget method can't deserialize array of enums and returns

> "title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"

maybe someone can advice something

```
 [HttpGet("find")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<SomeDTO>>> Find(SomeEnum []enums )
    {
       ....some service calls here
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

input like .../find?enums=1&enums=2

Comment: Share your code and input to the api.

Comment: added some code and used url pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly add `[FromQuery]` attribute to your parameter, like:

```
[HttpGet("find")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<SomeDTO>>> Find([FromQuery] SomeEnum[] enums )
{
    // ...some service calls here
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: thank you really much!!! i've been surfing in web for about 2 hours and haven't find any solution. Where did you find that solution? maybe some good book or msdn ?

Comment: @Nakipatop sorry, but I cannot point you to docs, but if you try to debug your app, you will find that asp.net selects Body model binder (from request body), which checks content type of your request (which is empty), that why you see unsupported content type, and add attribute to force asp.net to use query